# How to make a parent menu item only direct to its link on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All menu items and sub item of my site are links. So, when I click on parent item that has sub items it opens the sub menu. Only when I click on it for the second time it will take me to the its referred link.

Here how I did with JS and CSS:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('ul#main-nav > li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e) {
        if ( $(window).width() < 768 ) {   
          if ( !$(e.target).closest('ul').is('.sub-menu') ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$(this).hasClass('important')) {
              $(this).addClass('important');
            } else { 
              window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            }
          }
        }
    });
});

ul.sub-menu{display:none;}

.important > ul.sub-menu{
    display:block;
}
.important{
    display: block;
}
```

This is the basic HTML structure:

```
<ul id="main-nav" class="nav fl">
    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-27 parent">
        <a href="https://www.schoemanlaw.co.za/services/">Legal Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4306" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-97 current_page_item current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-4306 parent">
                <a href="https://www.schoemanlaw.co.za/services/commercial-law/">Commercial Law</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-4331" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-97 current_page_item menu-item-4331">
                        <a href="https://www.schoemanlaw.co.za/services/commercial-law/">General</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-4556" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-4556 parent">
                        <a href="#">Registration and Administration of Business Entities</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-4317" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4317">
                                <a href="https://www.schoemanlaw.co.za/services/registration-and-administration-of-companies/">Companies</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-4316" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4316">
                                <a href="https://www.schoemanlaw.co.za/services/registration-and-administration-of-co-operatives/">Co-operatives</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I do the same to the sub items link that also have sub items?

Comment: Please post css too

Comment: Just to summarise - you have headings and subcontents, but you only want a click to operate a link on the subcontents?  
(i.e. are the parent headings (About, Testimonials) are only for opening the sub-menu that contains the links, or are they also links but only when clicked for a second time?)

Comment: The parent headings are also links. So the page redirect can only happen when I click twice yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this to your js and let me know if it works.

```
$('ul#main-nav > li.menu-item-has-children > ul.sub-menu > li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e) {      
  e.preventDefault();
  if( $(this).hasClass('importante') ){
     window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  }
  else{
     $(this).addClass('importante');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $('button.dropdown-toggle').detach();
    $('ul#menu-main-menu>li').on("click", function(e){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("clicked")){
         // open menu
         $(this).addClass("clicked")
         e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
} );
```

Comment: I added the attribute location in the if statement and a css display block in the else statement but when I click on sub item it takes me to the parent menu item.
Mind sending a snippet that works?

Comment: I just realised, there is a easier way. Can you try the new code?

Comment: Did not work, but I hope you can give a touch from own answer

Comment: Can you setup the code in https://jsfiddle.net/
I don't see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this snippet that I used before but found one little detail:
When you click on a sub item, it goes to the respective page, but then all sub items from the menu show up.

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('ul#menu-main-menu > li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e) {
        if ($(window).width() < 1300) {   
          if (!$(e.target).closest('ul').is('.sub-menu')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!$(this).hasClass('important')) {
              $(this).addClass('important');
            } else { 
              window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            }
          }
        }
    });
});
```

CSS as it follows:

```
.important ul.sub-menu{
    display:block;
}
.important{
    display: block;
}
```

Here it is how it looks after clicking on 2015 theme

[image]